# JS Pasarle a un trigger el valor de una variable en el instante en que es creado

Tags: javascript, variables, eventos, trigger, bucles

Por ejemplo:

```
var items = jq(".li");
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    var item = jq(items[i]);
    item.click(function(i){
        console.log("i: ", i);
    });
}
```

El problema de este codigo es que cuando se dispara el evento click, i debuelve undefined. Imagino que esto pasa porque es en ese momento cuando va a buscar el valor de i el cual ya no existe pues el bucle ha finalizado.

¿Como puedo solucionar esto? No puedo pasar un parámetro a una función anónima.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre esta posibilidad, básicamente añádele un atributo a cada elemento que va a guardar el valor de `i`:

```
var items = jq(".li");
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var item = jq(items[i]);
        item.attr("dato",i);
        item.on("click",() => {
            console.log("i: ", jq(this).attr("dato"));
        });
    }
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Otra posible opción que se me ha ocurrido:

```
var items = jq(".li");
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var item = jq(items[i]);
        item.attr("dato",i);
        item.on("click",(i) => {
            paraCallback(i);
        });
    }

function paraCallback(i){
    console.log("i: ", i);
}
```

Comment: Lo había pensado, pero con esta opción el usuario podría modificar el valor del atributo con el inspector y es algo que no me puedo permitir en este caso. Gracias de todos modos!!

Comment: Otra opción es jugar con el `localStorage` del navegador, el problema es que el usuario también podría tener acceso a ese dato. Pero bueno el ejemplo sería que cada item tenga una id (item1, itme2,....  por ejemplo), y que en `localStorage` crees un item con clave la id de cada elemento `.li` y el valor que tu quieras

Comment: He agregado otra que no se si valdrá, pero por probar...